# Checking if JS variable matches a regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, match, indexof

How I can check that my variable match with this pattern `A|0`, `B|0`, `C|` ... `Z|0` in jQuery?

The pattern is `[one letter]|0`

```
if (myVar.indexOf((/^[A-Z]+$/+'|0') > -1){
  // true;
}
```

Comment: Note that jQuery is a framework primarily intended for amending the DOM. As you're working with regular expressions here you just need plain JS. I've retagged the question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that input your regex should look like this: `/^[A-Z]\|0$/`. `[A-Z]` matches the first uppercase character, then the pipe is escaped using `\|` before looking for the final `0` at the end of the input string. From there you can use `test()` to check whether the input meets that expression.

```js
['A|0', 'A0', 'B|0', '0|C', 'd|0'].forEach(item => {
  var result = /^[A-Z]\|0$/.test(item);
  console.log(item, result);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This following `regex` can match any integer after `|`

```js
['A|0', 'A0', 'B|0', '0|C', 'd|0'].forEach(str => {   
   var result =/^[A-Za-z]\|(\d+)$/.test(str);   
   console.log(str, result); 
})
```